# Giving a common _id to entries in different collections mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have three collections : Pages, Movies and Games
with respective schemas:

```
var pageschema = mongoose.Schema({
  name : { type: String, default: "Page name" },
  url: String,
  description: String,
  lid : { type : String, default: "lid" },
  logo: { type: String, default:"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/meBaze-Freebies/128/download.png" },
  clicks: { type:Number, default:0 },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

var movieschema = mongoose.Schema({
  name : { type: String, default: "Page name" },
  url: String,
  description: String,
  lid : { type : String, default: "lid" },
  logo: { type: String, default:"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/meBaze-Freebies/128/download.png" },
  clicks: { type:Number, default:0 },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

var gameschema = mongoose.Schema({
  name : { type: String, default: "Page name" },
  url: String,
  description: String,
  lid : { type : String, default: "lid" },
  logo: { type: String, default:"https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/meBaze-Freebies/128/download.png" },
  clicks: { type:Number, default:0 },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

Whenever I make a change(add, delete or update any entry) in "Movies" and "Games", the same change has to go in "Pages" as well.

I initially made a "lid" field to which I am giving the value of size of the "Pages" collection.
And alotted the same lid value to entry made in "Pages" and entry made in "Games" or "Movies". It worked for me for adding, and when i want to delete a document from "Movies" or "Games" collection, I delete the document with same lid from "Pages" as well, but now adding a new document is resulting in duplicacy of lid.

So, is there anyway i can give the same _id to "Pages" entry as well while entering in "Games" or "Movies" because i know that mongodb gives unique id always so there wont be duplicacy issue.

Thanks in advance! I am a begineer so any help would be appreciated. :)